# Can't retrieve list of defined trigger types from FH

Tags: smarttarget

In a SDL SmartTarget 2011 SP2 on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 implementation I get this error in the cd_smarttarget log and cd_core log. It mentions a `NoClassDefFoundError` and says `can't retrieve list of defined trigger types from FH`. Which JAR am I missing?

```
2014-08-29 12:50:16,736 DEBUG TriggerTypesHelper - Started fredhopper query call
2014-08-29 12:50:16,743 ERROR WebServiceExecutor - Fredhopper Web service call failed during execution
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/core/util/FeaturesAndProperties
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.webservice.WebServiceExecutor.executeTask(WebServiceExecutor.java:64) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.triggers.TriggerTypesHelper.getTriggerTypes(TriggerTypesHelper.java:85) [smarttarget_core.jar:na]
  ...(removed a part for brevity)...
2014-08-29 12:50:16,744 DEBUG WebServiceExecutor - Fredhopper Web service call for retrieved result in: 9 ms.
2014-08-29 12:50:16,744 ERROR TriggerTypesProcessor - can't retrieve list of defined trigger types from FH
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/core/util/FeaturesAndProperties` indicates jersey-core.jar is missing.

You need to copy those JARs from the SDL Tridion SP1 installation media:

- Tridion 2011 SP1\roles\webservice\java\third-party-lib\jersey-core.jar
- Tridion 2011 SP1\roles\webservice\java\third-party-lib\jsr311-api.jar

Without those JARs the errors mentioned above will occur and the `taf:claim:ambientdata:definedtriggertypes` will not be set in the ADF claimstore. SmartTarget needs this information in the claimstore and will complain by logging `ERROR AmbientDataHelper - can't find defined trigger-types in claim store (check if your smarttarget cartridge is up and running)`.

Without the definedtriggertypes claim the SmartTarget will work, but the queries to SDL Fredhopper are not optimized.